# Why should we use eventemitter together with @output in angular?

Tags: angular

Why should we use eventemitter together with @output in angular? And why @input does not need eventemitter ?

Comment: Read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple response is that, in child you have the oportunity to know when a input value has changed (using onChange hook).

However, in a parent you need react to an event (which can emit a value or not).

This say angular:

> The child component uses the `@[Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output)()`
>  property to raise an event to notify the parent of the change. To raise an event, an `@[Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output)()`
>  must have the type of `[EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)`
> , which is a class in `@angular/core`
>  that you use to emit custom events.